# ffmpeg cut same video to multiple pieces

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, subtitles, linux

For the project that I'm working on I have to cut some parts of same video with some subtitles. So I made a bash file that executes multiple ffmpeg commands like this.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale="w=640:h=-2",drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/verdana.ttf: textfile='1.txt': fontcolor=white: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=((h-text_h)/2)+90:" -ss 00:00:45.674 -to 00:00:50.093 -async 1 ./out/1.mp4

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale="w=640:h=-2",drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/verdana.ttf: textfile='2.txt': fontcolor=white: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=((h-text_h)/2)+90:" -ss 00:00:49.344 -to 00:00:52.971 -async 1 ./out/2.mp4
```

but it fast for first times (start) of the input file, it gets slower if I want to start seeking from middle or near end of input. So it gets nearly 7-8 minutes for 22. minute of the input file...

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale="w=640:h=-2",drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/verdana.ttf: textfile='226.txt': fontcolor=white: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=((h-text_h)/2)+90:" -ss 00:22:23.345 -to 00:22:25.846 -async 1 ./out/226.mp4
```

Anybody knows better way to do that?
Can I do that without seeking file each time? (Because it seems this is a seeking problem to me....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ss/to as input options. This seeks at the demuxer stage, which is much faster.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:22:23.345 -to 00:22:25.846 -i input.mp4 ...
```

You'll need a very recent build of ffmpeg (> Nov 19 2017)

Comment: I have already, should I move them before input file as parameter to executable?

Comment: -ss must be before the input file to be applied at the read-stage like the example shows

Comment: I'll try to build with recent source... Current ffmpeg under ubuntu is not accepting like this.

Comment: `-ss` as demuxer option is old, but `-to` wasn't implemented till the date stated.

Comment: can't make it working with ffmpe3 
Option to (record or transcode stop time) cannot be applied to input url input.mp4 -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
Error parsing options for input file input.mp4.
Error opening input files: Invalid argument

Comment: Use the git version from https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/